# Firebase authorization with email and password and give access to Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, authorization

I need to give access to Realtime Database if the user types in an email and password that match with the email inside Firebase Authorization. [image]

And I need to set rules into Realtime Database
for instance: if email and pass is matched -> give access to read and write data

Answer (score 0):

The below rule will allow any logged-in user (Firebase authentication) to access the realtime DB data.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": "auth.uid != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tested this up in rules playground
Even if I delete all emails, I still can read and modify Realtime Database

Comment: Did it work in rules playgroud and not work in live app? If that is the case, did you publish the rules?

Comment: yes I published rules

Comment: Try uninstalling/clearing cache?